# sklearn SVM custom kernel

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kernel, svm

I need to implement a custom kernel in `sklearn`.

This would be a custom linear kernel:

```
def my_kernel(x, y):
    return np.dot(x, y.T)
```

But I am having trouble doing something like RBF kernel. Is it possible to do that in sklearn  a custom kernel?

I have tried this:

```
def my_kernel(x, y):
    gamma = 0.01
    return np.exp((gamma* np.power(np.linalg.norm(x-y),2)))`
```

But did not work.

(I know that there is a pre-implementation of RBF, but I need to manually implement it, because I need to add some parameters)

Comment: you are missing the minus sign before gamma. Check out the normal distribution equation.

Comment: tried that, same problem

Comment: Also, kernel function should use MATRIX X and MATRIX Y and return MATRIX of kernel values (gram matrix), not just one element.

Comment: "But did not work." To be more help, we'll have to know *what* didn't work - did it not execute, did it not produce the expected behaviour, what was the expected behaviour. As @lennon310 mentions - there is a good example in the documentation. Have you tried that? What didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Your function looks good. Just use

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

There is [an example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html) related to your application.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented somthing like this

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
def gaussian_kernel(X, Y):
    kernel = euclidean_distances(X, Y) ** 2
    kernel = kernel*(-1/(self.gamma**2))
    kernel = np.exp(kernel)
    return kernel
```

and then have called svm with my defined kernel

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=gaussian_kernel, max_iter = 10000)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

this seemed to work fine. The only this that I failed to do was pass a hyperparameter from svm to my implementation of kernel, so I started defining the hyper-parameter globally instead as a work around.

As you would see I have defined a self.gamma which I wanted to tune but the gamma defining while initializing svm was not passing to my function.